# Parametrize the curve defined as the square with the vertices 1,-1,i and -i on the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to solve $$\int_C \frac{\operatorname{tg}(\frac{z}{2})}{z^2-16}dz$$ where C is defined as the frontier of the square with the vertices 1,-1,i and -i and im having trouble finding a way to parametrize this curve so i can apply $\int_a^b f(z(t)) z'(t)dt$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parametrrize all the sides of the square differently. Let me do one of the sides; line joining -i and i i.e., line joining (1,-1) and (1,1). The parametrisation of this line is $t(1,-1)+(1-t)(1,1)=(1, -2t+1),\;\;0\leq t\leq 1,$ or in other words, $z=1+i(1-2t).$ Now you can integrate along this curve. Similarly use my techniques to parametric other sides of the square and integrate along those sides as well. So you will have the given integral is equal to sum of four integrals. Orient the curve accordingly.

Comment: I think you paramatrized the contour of a square with the edges parellel to the axes. However i understood the reasoning. I used the following parametrisations: (1-t,t) , (-t,1-t), (t-1,-t),(t,t-1) with $ 0\leq t\leq 1 $. Thank you!